# How to build ruby 1.8.7 for i386 on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm attempting to build ruby 1.8.7 on OS X. This is only for one project so I need to build from source and not use a package manager because I don't want to overwrite the older build of ruby I use for everything else.

Ruby 1.9.X supports --with-arch in ./configure but 1.8.7 doesn't seem to.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM is your best friend for this sort of thing: http://rvm.io/

Comment: I don't think RVM actually solves the problem because it doesn't let me select specific patchlevels of ruby. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You can install specific patch levels.  See:  http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/installing/

Comment: I keep getting the x64 version. How to get i386?

Comment: Try using the environment variables Henry shows in his example, before you do `rvm install`.

Answer (score 1):

RVM seems like a good solution. An alternative is to just download the source and set the appropriate environment variables to build it as x86.

assuming bash:
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"  CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386" ./configure
will configure things for i386.

-- Henry